# Phoenix: How to supervise an Agent?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to use Agent as a store. However, I'm getting issues that the key I'm storing the data under does not exist.

Here is my channel:

```
  def join("user_pool:" <> email, %{ "app" => app }, socket) do
    Logger.info "PRODUCTION user_pool email: #{email}, app: #{app}"
    socket = assign(socket, :email, email)
    socket = assign(socket, :app, app)

    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: :"#{email}") # <---------------- should start link here
    {:ok, socket}
  end


  def handle_in("approve_match", %{ "matched_client_email" => matched_client_email }, socket) do
    Logger.info "approve_match"
    current_user_email = socket.assigns[:email]

    Agent.update :"#{current_user_email}", fn state ->
      Map.put(state, matched_client_email, true)
    end

    match_accepted = Agent.get(:"#{matched_client_email}", &(Map.get(&1, current_user_email))) # <----------- breaks here. says they matched_client_email key does not exist in Agent.
    Logger.info "#{matched_client_email} has approved #{current_user_email}: #{match_accepted}"
    case match_accepted do
      true ->
        VideoChat.Endpoint.broadcast(
          "user_pool:#{matched_client_email}",
          "match_accepted",
          %{ matched_client_email: socket.assigns[:email] }
        )
        {:noreply, socket}
      _ ->
        Logger.info "2nd person has yet to approve"
        {:noreply, socket}
    end
  end
```

I was suggested to create a supervisor for this, but I'm not sure how. I know I have to add something to the commented out line in lib/my_app.exs but I can't find what. I'm also not 100% sure this would fix my issue.

```
  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec

    # Define workers and child supervisors to be supervised
    children = [
      # Start the Ecto repository
      supervisor(VideoChat.Repo, []),
      # Start the endpoint when the application starts
      supervisor(VideoChat.Endpoint, []),
      # Start your own worker by calling: VideoChat.Worker.start_link(arg1, arg2, arg3)
      # worker(VideoChat.Worker, [arg1, arg2, arg3]),
    ]

    # See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: VideoChat.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just uncomment

```
# worker(VideoChat.Worker, [])
```

passing the appropriate module instead of `VideoChat.Worker` there. The arguments will be passed to the respective `VideoChat.Worker.start_link` function. Once crashed, this particular `Agent` will be restarted. Below is a contrived example:

**lib/my_app.ex**

```
children = [
  # Start the Ecto repository
  supervisor(VideoChat.Repo, []),
  # Start the endpoint when the application starts
  supervisor(VideoChat.Endpoint, []),
  # start our own agent
  worker(VideoChat.Store, [])
]
```

**lib/video_chat/store.ex**

```
defmodule VideoChat.Store do
  @moduledoc "The store, based on `Agent`."

  def start_link do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  @doc "Gets a value"
  @spec get(String.t) :: Map.t
  def get(key) do
    Agent.get(__MODULE__, &Map.get(&1, key))
  end

  @doc "Puts a value"
  @spec put(String.t, {String.t, any}) :: Map.t
  def put(key, {inner_key, inner_value}) do
    # more sophisticated implementation,
    # possibly based on `Agent.get_and_update/3`
  end
end
```

[`Agent.get_and_update/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#get_and_update/3).

Answer (score 1):

Please consider [this example](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#module-module-based-supervisors). It supervises GenServer, but Agent *is* GenServer, so it will be very similar to code.

First of all, you should create your own Module to supervise - it will use internally Agent (just like in example from doc, but there the GenServer is wrapped).

Then you can create your own Supervisor module and in `init` function you declare children as a workers eg.

```
children = [ worker(MyAgent, [[]])] # [] as an initial state
```

And you also in the `init` use `supervise` to select strategy how it should works, when one of these workers crash.

To supervise processes, you have to start the Supervisor before and it should start all of his children workers with initial state.